# Php code to dynamically display products report

Tags: php, pdo

I am moving my POS Software to web base version, Everything is going perfectly well until i wanted to display Sales product dynamically.

list of products

[image]

sales table

[image]

i use implode to insert my record which work well when i explode.

The issues here is that i want to display all the sales base on product i.e from sales table explode product_id and use each id to get product name.

Also explode quantity and add all the quantity together base on product Id and also explode real price and display it and so on.

what I am getting which is not what i want

[image]

This is what i want

[image]

```html
 <table id="salestable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr class="titlerow" role="row">
                      <th >Products</th>
                      <th >Sold</th>
                      <th >Cost</th>
                      <th >Income</th>
                      <th >Profit</th>  
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="get_product">
                 <?php
                 try{       
    $query = $con->prepare("Select  s.product_id, s.adjust_price, s.real_price, s.quantity,  s.sales_date from tbl_sales s where s.status ='Paid' and  s.store_id = '$store'");
    $query->execute();
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        ?>      
            <tr>
            <td ><?php foreach(explode("|", $row['product_id']) as  $pID){ get_product_by_id($con, $pID); } ?></td>
            <td ><?php foreach(explode("|", $row['quantity']) as  $qty){ echo $qty; } ?></td>
            <td ><?php foreach(explode("|", $row['real_price']) as  $cost){ echo $cost; } ?></td>
            <td ><?php foreach(explode("|", $row['adjust_price']) as  $income){ echo $income; } ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo '2'; ?></td>
            </tr><?php


                                }                                


    } catch (PDOException $e){
                $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
                $log = date('Y-m-d H:m:s').' '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].' '.$e->getMessage(). "\r\n";
            file_put_contents('../errorlog.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);
}
                    ?>   </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                      <tr class="totalColumn">
                        <th >Products</th>
                      <th class="totalCol" >Sold</th>
                      <th class="totalCol" >Cost</th>
                      <th class="totalCol" >Income</th>
                      <th class="totalCol" >Profit</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="footersearch">
<td colspan="8" ><input type="text" class="form-control" name="search_table" id="search_table" title="Type & hit enter to search the table" data-toggle="tooltip" placeholder="Type & hit enter to search the table" style="width:100%;"></td>
</tr>
                    </tfoot>
                  </table>
```

Comment: No, no, no. You don't want to store serialized datas (`11|12|14|3`) in your database. This goes against the purpose of using a relational database. [Normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables and use `FOREIGN KEY` constraints. Creating, Reading, Updating and Deleting datas will become really easier to manage

Comment: Why are you storing multiple products in one line?

Comment: This is Point of sales software and multiple customer will buy multiple products. i just just to have a particular transaction in online. We can have over 100 transaction in aday. what if 100 customers purchase 100 items, that will be bogus. Updating sales and editing sales is easier with it. report is waht is giving me problem

Comment: Sorry to say but @Cid is correct here. Please don't build systems like that.

Comment: @Opeyemiademon I'm curious to see the query you are using to update the price of the product with id 11

Comment: I'd love to see how easy it is to write the query that fetch the count of each product sold, and the amount of money it brought

Comment: If you have 100 customers buying 100 products in a day, that will result 10 000 entries. If this happens every days for 10 years, you'll have 36 500 000 entries in your table. And there is **nothing wrong** with it. Databases are made for that. That will become **really faster** to query the 36 500 000 rows than the serialized 365 000 ones, because they will be indexed

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Cid's comment above, in case you don't get what he means by normalization.

If you want to link a sale or invoice to a customer, you'll need a Customer table and an Invoice table. If you don't want to keep up with customer information, just use an Invoice table. One way to link items sold to an Invoice would be with a relation called ProductInInvoice as shown below. This pseudocode isn't valid SQL, but you'll get the idea.

```
Products (
  productId,
  name,
  description,
  price,
  ...
);

Invoice (
  invoiceId
);

ProductInInvoice (
  productId,
  invoiceId,
  quantitySold
);
```

Here, `productId` in the ProductInInvoice table is a foreign key into the Products table, and `invoiceId` is a foreign key into the Invoice table.

If you had a Customer table with a `customerId` column to store customer info., you could add a foreign key `customerId` to the Invoice table that refers to the Customer table. Then you could query to find out not only how many of each item was sold in that transaction, but also who bought them, by joining tables in a SELECT statement.

Comment: I understand what he ment pefectly. infact i can implement that with foreign key without any problem. Just that Am almost done with this project and i already explode my record. Am afraid i dont want to start afresh

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I've refactored my current project over and over again for weeks. Finally ran it for the first time today.